# PostgreSQL update statement to substring a column value

Tags: sql, postgresql

Considering XPT table containing the following values:

```
123, 443, 213, 124
```

I want to update it remove the last character of each number in order to get it like this:

```
12, 44, 21, 12
```

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Tell us what you already tried and what is not working.

Answer (score 1):

Use `SUBSTRING()` function:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(t.value, 1, 2)
    FROM XPT t;
```

Or if you want to update:

```
UPDATE XPT t
    SET t.value = SUBSTRING(t.value, 1, 2);
```

Comment: its possible using inner join this substring?

Comment: not working 
select substring (nuts3_resid_1amc,1,2) as source from dados inner join nuts02   on (dados.source= nuts02.id) where nuts3_resid_1amc='117'

Comment: ERROR: column dados.source does not exist

Comment: So you don't have a column `source` in table dados.. the error is pretty clear. @user2964140

Comment: Don't you have an `ID` column connects to `nuts02` table ?

Comment: I have to match the nut 3 to nut2 this is I have to go get nut3 and know what the nut2.